# Windows batch output

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am working on a programming assignment using Windows batch. We are supposed to retrieve the following information:

1. Amount of free space of c: drive in bytes
2. Percentage of processor time
3. Memory capacity in bytes

Here are my answers:

1. `dir C:\ | find "Dir(s)"`
2. `wmic cpu get loadpercentage`
3. `wmic memorychip get capacity`

We were also instructed to output all of this to a single text file. I don't have that much experience using batch commands. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: If you want to redirect the output to a file, read about [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: Dir ../ >> textfile

Comment: `WMIC` can also retrieve the drive freespace too, _(in a none language dependent way)_, and it additionally has options `/OUTPUT` and `/APPEND`, which you may find useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get this done, is using the `>` and `>>` commands, where:

```
">" means : (re)create the file and write inside it. (If the file already exists, delete it first)
">>" means : append to the file.
```

This becomes the following in your case:

```
dir C:\ | find "Dir(s)"       > C:\whatever_directory\outputfile.txt
wmic cpu get loadpercentage  >> C:\whatever_directory\outputfile.txt
wmic memorychip get capacity >> C:\whatever_directory\outputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

> **`> file_out.log (command + command + command)`**, or variants ::

```bat
(
dir C:\ | find "Dir(s)"
"%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic" cpu get loadpercentage
"%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic" memorychip get capacity
) >d:\path\file_name.log

rem :: or ... 

>d:\path\file_name.log (
dir C:\ | find "Dir(s)"
"%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic" cpu get loadpercentage
"%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic" memorychip get capacity
) 

rem :: or ... 
>d:\path\file_name.log (dir C:\ | find "Dir(s)" & "%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic" cpu get loadpercentage & "%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic" memorychip get capacity) 

rem :: or ... 
(dir C:\ | find "Dir(s)" & "%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic" cpu get loadpercentage & "%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic" memorychip get capacity) >d:\path\file_name.log
```

---